# Looking for a specific alternate word for proved

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a very specific word to be used in place of *{word}* in this sentence:

> He {word} himself well.

An alternate sentence that would have a similar meaning:

> He proved capable in the task.

The most I can remember of the word I'm looking for is that is has the prefix *re-*.

**Edit:**
Redeemed is close to what I'm looking for but I don't want the negative connotation around the word.

To give my specific use case example, I was given some new temporary responsibilities at work and I'm writing my quarterly goals. I'm looking to make one of these goals that I handled these new responsibilities well.

**Edit:**
So much for a good memory, the specific word does not use the prefix *re-*.

Comment: Thanks for the edit choster, was not sure which formatting to use for the sentences. I am unsure however about the - after re, perhaps I'm using the wrong word when I say prefix. To my memory the word is not hyphenated.

Comment: "Represented", maybe?

Comment: Could you be thinking of ***"He redeemed himself"***?  I know that "redeem" and "proved" are not synonymous but "he redeemed himself" is a very idiomatic phrase (without the "well" at the end).

Comment: Redeemed was one of the first words that comes to mind, but I feel that it has a bit of a negative connotation. Generally you would have done something wrong and then redeemed that wrong.

Comment: After its miserable performance in the Olympic Games the German nation redeemed itself by winning the World Cup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps the word **[acquitted](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/acquitted)**. According to *Collins English Dictionary*, it can mean

> to perform (one's part); conduct (oneself)

A fairly standard, if somewhat formal statement is *He acquitted himself well.*

Comment: Ok so my specification for the prefix was completely off base, this is the exact word I was looking for.

Comment: @phaeze After ruining my mind with the prefix #_#

Answer (score 3):

You may be thinking of:

> He represented himself well.

It's not a terribly common way to express that idea, but I have heard it.

The more common alternative I've heard is:

> He acquitted himself well.

But that one doesn't start with 're'.

Comment: This is much closer than redeemed and I may use it if I can't find the exact word I'm thinking of.

Comment: Oops. I see @bib posted the 'correct' answer while I was editing mine. Oh, well. I'll just leave it, but you should up-vote his since it was first.

Answer (score 0):

> The most I can remember of the word I'm looking for is that is has the prefix re-.

Could what you are looking for be *He redeemed himself*?  It means to make up for poor past performance or to remove a prior bad impression.

Comment: Care to say why you downvoted?

Comment: Because the request is for a word that means something like "performed well". To redeem oneself is to perform well only in a situation where one had previously performed badly but there's no mention of that requirement isn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Fair enough. (The request also said "The word I'm looking for ... has the prefix re-", but the accepted answer was *acquitted*...)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a good answer to your question is "legitimized."  Maybe "demonstrated?"

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. Please take a moment to find upvoted answers to see the type of answer this site is looking for. We also provide [help on answering questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). In particular, a referenced statement rather than conjecture ["Maybe"] tends to go down well. (Note: the system will automatically downvote some answers which it flags as capable of improvement in this regard.)